# xpath scraping data from the second page

Tags: html, xpath, google-sheets

I am trying to scrape data from this webpage: http://webfund6.financialexpress.net/clients/zurichcp/PortfolioPriceTable.aspx?SchemeID=33, and I specifically need data for fund number 26.

Have no problem getting data from the first page with this address (funds number 1-25), but for the hell of me can't scrape anything from the second page.  Can someone help?

Thanks!

Here is the code I use: in Google Sheets:

=IMPORTXML("http://webfund6.financialexpress.net/clients/zurichcp/PortfolioPriceTable.aspx?SchemeID=33","/html/body/form[@id='MainForm']/table/tr/td/div[@id='main']/div[@id='tabResult']/div[@id='Prices']/table/thead/tr[26]/td[@class='Center'][1]")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do 2 things - one is to append the `PgIndex=2` onto the end of your URL, and then you can also significantly simplify your xpath to this:

```
//*[@id='Prices']//tr[2]/td[2]
```

This specifically grabs the second row on the table (tr which means table-row), in order to bypass the header row, then grabs the second field which is the table-data cell.

```
=IMPORTXML("http://webfund6.financialexpress.net/clients/zurichcp/PortfolioPriceTable.aspx?SchemeID=33&PgIndex=2","//*[@id='Prices']//tr[2]/td[2]")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get the second page, add &PgIndex=2 to your url. Then adjust the /table/thead/tr[26] to /table/thead/tr[2]. The result is:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://webfund6.financialexpress.net/clients/zurichcp/PortfolioPriceTable.aspx?SchemeID=33&PgIndex=2","/html/body/form[@id='MainForm']/table/tr/td/div[@id='main']/div[@id='tabResult']/div[@id='Prices']/table/thead/tr[2]/td[@class='Center'][1]")
```

Comment: Ed, Many thanks!  I've been struggling with this silly thing for ages; you really helped.

Comment: Great! If this answered your question, please approve the answer. Thanks,